# MySQL comparing 2 DATETIME values of unknown type

Tags: mysql, datetime

It sounds simple but I'm stuck. What I want is to be able to compare two MySQL DATETIME values but due to the open ended nature of how the queries are formed I do not know the datatype of value 1 or value 2. For instance, each value can either be a string that is input by an end user, a date field or a DATETIME field.

Example:

dateTime1 > 1/18/2017 2:30pm

The issue I'm running into is STR_TO_DATE() expects a string and returns null with DATETIME, DATE_FORMAT() expects a date and returns null with a string. I need a function or nested group of functions that will give me the same result regardless of the value of the datatype & would like to address directly in mysql rather than pre-processing or making the user input validation stricter. I used to use CAST(value, DATETIME), however CAST() doesn't read the date correctly in the more recent versions of MySQL (it ignores the am/pm specification). Any ideas?

Comment: Fix your system so it stores data in the correct types.  Have users select dates from drop down lists or calendars.

Comment: Its more complex than that since the end user values can be any format, not necessarily a date. The function the user assigns to the value in different parts of the system determines the datatype of the value. I can pre-process the values based on the function, however a pure MySQL solution would be much more simplified. Was thinking something along the lines of IF(typeOf(value) = "DATETIME", value, STR_TO_DATE(value)) but I'm not aware of a typeOf() function like that in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

GREATEST() did not work for me as it would always return null if any component was null, however it led me to COALESCE() which provides me with the solution I am looking for as it returns the first non NULL value. It makes the assumption the value will always be DATE, DATETIME, or a date time string which is the case for my issue:

SELECT COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE(value1, '%c/%e/%Y %r'), value1) > COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE(value2, '%c/%e/%Y %r'), value2)

Note: value1 and value2 are either DATE / DATETIME columns or date time string values

Comment: You are right about `coalesce()`!  Sorry for my inaccurate answer before.  I updated my answer to suggest the use of `coalesce()` instead of `greatest()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using the `coalesce()` function, with a list of different formats used with `str_to_date()`.  `coalesce()` will ignore any null from the list (but at least one of them should be non-null, or you still get a null).

```
select 
  coalesce(
      str_to_date('13/18/2017 2:30pm', '%m/%e/%Y %l:%i%p')    -- will get a null
      , str_to_date('18/13/2017 2:30pm', '%e/%m/%Y %l:%i%p')  -- will get a null 
      , str_to_date('18/01/2017 14:30', '%e/%m/%Y %k:%i')
  ) as answer;
```

The code may be brittle, because there are so many different date/time formats that a human user may input.

You may also need to be very familiar with all the different format characters that `str_to_date()` take.  See this manual page for more details:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

**Updated**

An earlier version of this answer incorrectly suggested the use of the `greatest()` function.